# Launch x86 or x64 MSI from MSBuild bootstrapper

Tags: msbuild, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

So I have a WiX based MSI that installs a handful of device drivers and therefore I have an x64 and an x86 version. The package also has a .NET 3.5 dependency so I'm generating a bootstrapper to do this and then launch the MSI. My question is if anyone is aware of a way to create a bootstrapper that will detect the platform it is running on and launch the appropriate MSI. I've googled around for such a solution and have turned up nothing so far. Thanks!

Comment: well I once read that MSIs are platform-specific by design

Comment: Right, which is why there are two separate MSIs. However, let's say I'm distributing this on a CD and have an autorun.inf that launches my "setup.exe" bootstrapper- currently I can only point that to one .msi to be launched by the bootstrapper once it has finished laying down prereqs

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Windows Installer requires a separate MSI package for x86 and x64.

With WiX v3.6+ Burn provides the functionality to "bundle" the two packages together into a single install (driven by the Burn executable).  You could do it with a .wxs file that would something a little like:

```
<Bundle ...>
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense' />

  <Chain>
    <MsiPackage InstallCondition='NOT VersionNT64' SourceFile='path\to\x86.msi' />
    <MsiPackage InstallCondition='VersionNT64' SourceFile='path\to\x64.msi' />
  </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

That's just beginning to scratch the surface of everything that Burn can do but it shows how to bundle the two architecture packages into a single installation experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you're installing .Net before launching your msi you could also include an exe written in c# that detects your platform and then passes the answer back to your bootstrapper.

I used an exe that detected the platform, created a reg key that I was verifying to decide what to launch.

[C# example](http://beta.channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/410567-C-Detect-32-bit-or-64-bit-OS/?CommentID=431098)

Answer (score 0):

[dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) is probably what you need to use: you can create different "setup" configurations which will only be triggered if the right combination of OS, platform and language are met. You can also embed any MSIs, prerequisites etc. into the setup executable so users only have a single file to download/run.